# adding numeric strings with commas

Tags: php, mysql, string, numbers, addition

I have a loop going which adds results from my database. The values are numeric strings in this format: $$$,$$$.$$ I am having trouble getting the results to add up and display in that same format:

```
function totals (){ 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM postmeta WHERE postmeta.meta_key = 'Value'");
    $value = 0;
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        $value = $value + str_replace(',', '', $row['meta_value']);
    }
    echo "Worth $".$value."!";
};
```

Using the above, I get something like Worth $653987.32!. Now I need to  reinsert the commas so I try this:

```
$value = number_format($value, 2, '.', ',');
```

But then I get Worth $10,000.00!

Output as requested:

```
    original: 5,000.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 19.95   numeric: 20 
    original: 28.00   numeric: 28 
    original: 3,777.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 2,500.00   numeric: 2 
    original: 575.00   numeric: 575 
    original: 4,000.00   numeric: 4 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 1,500.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 343.50   numeric: 344 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 1,070.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 305.00   numeric: 305 
    original: 1,000.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 1144.99   numeric: 1,145 
    original: 900.00   numeric: 900 
    original: 3,750.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 1,750   numeric: 1 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 200.00   numeric: 200 
    original: 619.00   numeric: 619 
    original: 200.00   numeric: 200 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 2,699.00   numeric: 2 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 10,000.00   numeric: 10 
    original: 500.00   numeric: 500 
    original: 186.00   numeric: 186 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 39,000.00   numeric: 39 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 8,330.00   numeric: 8 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 4,875.00   numeric: 4 
    original: 1,000.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 3,135.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 15,000.00   numeric: 15 
    original: 400.00   numeric: 400 
    original: 75.00   numeric: 75 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 6,893.00   numeric: 6 
    original: 330.00   numeric: 330 
    original: 484.96   numeric: 485 
    original: 8,600.00   numeric: 8 
    original: 2,500.00   numeric: 2 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 6,150.00   numeric: 6 
    original: 500.00   numeric: 500 
    original: 275.00   numeric: 275 
    original: 900.00   numeric: 900 
    original: 750.00   numeric: 750 
    original: 450.00   numeric: 450 
    original: 4,600.00   numeric: 4 
    original: 299.50   numeric: 300 
    original: 250.00   numeric: 250 
    original: 825.00   numeric: 825 
    original: 750.00   numeric: 750 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 2,000.00   numeric: 2 
    original: 16,000   numeric: 16 
    original: 2,600.00   numeric: 2 
    original: 240.00   numeric: 240 
    original: 4,500.00   numeric: 4 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 6,000.00   numeric: 6 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 3,000.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 15,000.00   numeric: 15 
    original: 45,987.24   numeric: 45 
    original: 1,100.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 20,000.00   numeric: 20 
    original: 5,100.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 12,000.00   numeric: 12 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 550.00   numeric: 550 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 150.00   numeric: 150 
    original: 4,500.00   numeric: 4 
    original: 1,500.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 1,758.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 450.00   numeric: 450 
    original: 400.00   numeric: 400 
    original: 28.00   numeric: 28 
    original: 20.00   numeric: 20 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 20.00   numeric: 20 
    original: 22.00   numeric: 22 
    original: 99.00   numeric: 99 
    original: 500.00   numeric: 500 
    original: 500.00   numeric: 500 
    original: 33,080.00   numeric: 33 
    original: 3,000.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 5,000.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 25,000.00   numeric: 25 
    original: 25,750.00   numeric: 25 
    original: 5,000.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 1,800.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 419.75   numeric: 420 
    original: 600.00   numeric: 600 
    original: 130.00   numeric: 130 
    original: 1,000.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 650.00   numeric: 650 
    original: 650.00   numeric: 650 
    original: 285.00   numeric: 285 
    original: 949.00   numeric: 949 
    original: 500.00   numeric: 500 
    original: 798.80   numeric: 799 
    original: 279.50   numeric: 280 
    original: 369.90   numeric: 370 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 5,000.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 1,995.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 1,800.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 3,316.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 17,182.28   numeric: 17 
    original: 30,000.00   numeric: 30 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 0.00   numeric: 0 
    original: 880.00   numeric: 880 
    original: 12.00   numeric: 12 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 5,600.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 1,600.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 100.00   numeric: 100 
    original: 14.95   numeric: 15 
    original: 6,000.00   numeric: 6 
    original: 7,400.00   numeric: 7 
    original: 750.00   numeric: 750 
    original: 1,575.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 50.00   numeric: 50 
    original: 3,500.00   numeric: 3 
    original: 5,000.00   numeric: 5 
    original: 1,000.00   numeric: 1 
    original: 6,500.00   numeric: 6 
    original: 14,375.00   numeric: 14 
    original: 9,500.00   numeric: 9 
    original: 91,343.00   numeric: 91 
    original: 22,610.00   numeric: 22 
    original: 15,000.00   numeric: 15 
    original: 10,000.00   numeric: 10
```

Clearly something isn't right. Can anyone help?

```
numeric total: 661,379 Original total: 661379.32
```

Comment: Sounds like your storing a numeric in a VARCHAR field in your db. You really should change the field to numeric and use the db's aggregate functions to do your calulations for you. I can't see the logic of storing a number as a string.

Comment: I can't. the numbers are being inserted by wordpress - everything is string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it output? It sounds like your number might be too big to fit in 31bits, but it's hard to know until i see your exact output.

Are you sure all of your `$row['meta_value']` values are straight numbers with commas? Try doing this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "Value: {$row['meta_value']}\n";
    $value += str_replace(',', '', $row['meta_value']);
}

echo "final value: $value\n";
echo "formatted: ".number_format($value, 2)."\n";
```

I wonder if some of the values are not as you expected.

Comment: can you add the first two lines to the end of your script - what is the $value before you try and format it?

Comment: oh! you *are* putting the `number_format()` line *after* the loop, right?

Comment: Getting closer... the numeric function is removing the decimal digits. How can I keep them?

Comment: just change `number_format($value)` to `number_format($value, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively cast the value into a floating number:

```
(float)str_replace(',','',$row['meta_value'])
```

**EDIT:**

Full code:

```
function totals () { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT meta_value FROM postmeta WHERE postmeta.meta_key = 'Value'");
    $value = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $value += (float)str_replace(',', '', $row['meta_value']);
    }
    echo "Worth \$$value!";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get them properly formatted from the query itself and operate on the field you want:

```
SELECT replace(meta_value, ',', '') as number_value, meta_value as original_value
FROM postmeta
WHERE postmeta.meta_key = 'Value'
```